# Android application doesn't read updated file until device restart

Tags: android, file, caching

My android application reads a data file from directory "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.myapp".
If I change this file and launch the application, the application displays the old version of the file, until I restart.
Even if I delete the file, the application continues to show the old file.

I tried to make a "clearcache" from onDestroy (), as explained on the page: https://medium.com/@droidbyme/clear-cache-in-android-programmatically-26a1405a470b
unsuccessful, by the way I no longer believe that this is linked to the application cache, but rather to a kind of filesystem cache.

I can put my data anywhere on the device, but not in the apk, because of the size of the data.

How can I force reading of the update data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I don't really know why.
I did a factory reset last week, maybe that's why.